# Doing a dynamic import in a loop, walking through the array, but I only get the first value

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to do a **dynamic import** so that my classes are pulled by information from json. In json, I only have classes specified that I need to get inside the script. I make paths from strings to json then put them in an array.I make an import and put the values ​​into an array. But as a result, I only get the value of the first import, the rest is undefined. Tell me how to correctly perform dynamic imports inside a loop, or is there a fundamentally different approach altogether?

**My index.js**:

```
var popupsConfig = myConfig.popups
var popups = []
async function getPopups(popupsConfig) {
    for (let i = 0; i < popupsConfig.length; i++) {
        let obj = await
        import (`../src/assets/popups/${myConfig.popups[i].popupType}`)
        popups.push(obj.default)
    }
}
getPopups(popupsConfig)
```

**My webpack.config**:

```
const webpack = require("webpack")
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: "eval-source-map",
    entry: {
        entry: ['babel-polyfill', '../dev/index.js'],
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 8080
    },
    experiments: {
        topLevelAwait: true
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@dev': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/')
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: '../dev/index.html'
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            CANVAS_RENDERER: JSON.stringify(true),
            WEBGL_RENDERER: JSON.stringify(true)
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
                use: ['file-loader']
            }, {
                test: [/\.vert$/, /\.frag$/],
                use: "raw-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**My .babelrc**:

```
{
  "plugins": ["dynamic-import-webpack", "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k76b.png)